# NSAttributedString text always sticks to bottom with big lineHeight

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to implement by-design labels coming from Sketch e.g. I need text styles with font size = 19 and line height = 50. So I ended up using `NSAttributedString` with `NSMutableParagraphStyle` but was stopped by problem with text being sticked to bottom of `UILabel`

I've already tried to use `lineHeightMultiple` and `lineSpacing` but those didn't give me the line height I wanted so I ended up using `minimumLineHeight` and `maximumLineHeight` equal the same

Here is my approach to make `NSAttributedString`

```swift
    private static func makeAttributedString(
        with attributes: TextAttributes,
        text: String? = nil,
        alignment: NSTextAlignment = .center
    ) -> NSAttributedString {
        let font = UIFont(name: attributes.font.rawValue, size: attributes.fontSize)!

        let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraph.alignment = alignment
        paragraph.paragraphSpacing = attributes.paragraph
        paragraph.minimumLineHeight = attributes.lineHeight // equal 50 in my case
        paragraph.maximumLineHeight = attributes.lineHeight // equal 50 in my case

        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraph,
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: attributes.textColor,
            NSAttributedStringKey.kern: attributes.kern,
            NSAttributedStringKey.font: font
        ]

        return NSAttributedString(string: text ?? "", attributes: attributes)
    }
```

I expect result similar to design

[image]

but actually getting

[image]

Note: setting height constraint to 50 is not applicable because I also need multiline labels but there is the same bug with them

Comment: Try to remove this line `paragraph.minimumLineHeight = attributes.lineHeight`. It works for me without it.

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi result is wrong - https://imgur.com/a/hSWr2VQ, I need resulting height like this - https://imgur.com/CoszbW7

Comment: Ok, I see. Are you using UILabel to display the text? If so, maybe it makes sense to set height constraint to that label with 50

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi its only applicable for single line uilabels I need to support both single line and multiline, but thx for advices!

Comment: I think approach is somehow connected with baselineOffset but idk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I've found some workaround myself, maybe it will help someone.

The method is about setting baselineOffset like this:

```swift
NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset: (attributes.lineHeight - font.lineHeight) / 4
```

Works like charm:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS6k0.png

Comment: In addition to my previous question, I found a better solution, you just need to override UILabels `drawText(in rect: CGRect)` function, modify `rect` parameter `origin.y` and call `super.drawText(in rect: CGRect)` with your modified `rect`

Comment: can you explain more? or give an example