# Set NSAttributedString center vertically each line using baselineOffset

Tags: swift, uilabel, center, nsattributedstring, baseline

I want to set label's line height and I use `minimumLineHeight` and `maximumLineHeight` of `NSMutableParagraphStyle`

```swift
extension UILabel {
    func setTextWithLineHeight(text: String?, lineHeight: CGFloat) {
        if let text = text {
            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight
            style.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight
            
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .paragraphStyle: style
                .baselineOffset: (lineHeight - font.lineHeight) / 4 // added!!️️
            ]
                
            let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: text,
                                                attributes: attributes)
            self.attributedText = attrString
        }
    }
}
```

I add `.baselineOffset` attribute based on a answer [NSAttributedString text always sticks to bottom with big lineHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973156/nsattributedstring-text-always-sticks-to-bottom-with-big-lineheight) , because without it, text is sticks to bottom like this.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTEjY.png)

What I want is set text center vertically so using baselineOffset, I solved the problem. However I wonder why it set baseOffline as `(attributes.lineHeight - font.lineHeight) / 4` not `(attributes.lineHeight - font.lineHeight) / 2`

Comment: Happens the same with me as well. Be aware, however, that there are some scenarios when the offset works as expected. There some more details in the article I'm writing on `UILabel` line height at http://blog.eppz.eu/uilabel-line-height-letter-spacing-and-more-uilabel-typography-extensions/, may or may not help. Also, see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124799 if any updates there.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 17+, `baselineOffset` works as expected.

For example, this code provides vertically centered text on the line.

```
let label = UILabel()
let lineHeight = 100.0
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight
let baselineOffset = (lineHeight - label.font.lineHeight) / 2.0
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Some text",
    attributes: [
        .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        .baselineOffset: baselineOffset
    ]
)
```

But on iOS 16 and lower, you have to divide the baseline offset twice: `let baselineOffset = (lineHeight - label.font.lineHeight) / 4.0` to receive the same result.

Be careful!